# Multiple Filters in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Need to filter the Data using multiple conditions based on record codes and date of services and count the distinct values based on the `col1`, `col2`,`col3`.

Having issue with the Pyspark parameters resolving during execution and returning no records.

```
from_dt = 01-01-2018
end_dt= 12-31-2018

df.filter((trim(df.code) =='AB') | (trim(df.code) =='CD') | (trim(df.code) =='F')).filter("from_dt >= '${0}' & end_dt <= ${1}'").select("col1","col2","col3").distinct().count()
```

Comment: Try keeping the entire contents of the filter in braces, also are you sure there will be some rows returned after applying these filters ?

Comment: Add sample input and expected output with output you are getting from your experiment